# Changing key's name in a array

Tags: php, arrays, key, unset

So, having an array like the following:

```
$input = [
    'first_name'   => 'Alex',
    'last_name'    => 'UFO',
    'email'        => 'test@test.com',
    'phone_number' => '124124',
    // .....
    'referral_first_name'   => 'Jason',
    'referral_last_name'    => 'McNugget',
    'referral_email'        => 'jingleball@nuggets.com',
    'referral_phone_number' => '1212415',
];
```

After processing the first part, until `referral...`, do you think of any better way to replace `referral_first_name` with `first_name` and so on, then the following? Maybe a more dynamic and automatic way.

```
$input['first_name'] = $input['referral_first_name'];
unset($input['referral_first_name']);

$input['last_name'] = $input['referral_last_name'];
unset($input['referral_last_name']);

$input['email'] = $input['referral_email'];
unset($input['referral_email']);

$input['phone_number'] = $input['referral_phone_number'];
unset($input['referral_phone_number']);
```

---

Guys, I forgot to mention, but I have already done it with `foreach`, but the problem will be when the array gets pretty large (and usually does, and not by one person using that function, but by many), and that would mean extra unnecessary processing time, since it has to iterate through the whole array, before reaching the `referral_..` part.

Comment: There is no other way, except for doing so when you create the array.

Comment: After remove `referral_` your keys duplicated and overwitten. Be careful on that. And you can see my answer and working demo

Answer (score 2):

you must create another array, this code should do it dynamically:

```
$newInput = array();
foreach($input as $key => $element){
    $newKey = explode("_", $key, 2);
    $newInput[$newKey[1]] = $element;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Recreating the array is the only way..

- Grab all the keys from the original array and put it in a temp array
- Use `array_walk` to modify that temp array to add the `referral` word to it
- Now use `array_combine` using the above keys and values from the old array.

---

#### The code..

```
<?php
$input = [
    'first_name'   => 'Alex',
    'last_name'    => 'UFO',
    'email'        => 'test@test.com',
    'phone_number' => '124124'];

$ak = array_keys($input);
array_walk($ak,function (&$v){ $v = 'referral_'.$v;});
$input=array_combine($ak,array_values($input));
print_r($input);
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
Array
(
    [referral_first_name] => Alex
    [referral_last_name] => UFO
    [referral_email] => test@test.com
    [referral_phone_number] => 124124
)
```

#### Since you are looking for performance , Use a typical `foreach`

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($input as $k=>$v ) {
$newarr["referral_".$k]=$v;
}
```

Comment: This looks really nice. I had a solution that involved using `foreach`, but don't really want to use it, since the array might get pretty large. So yea, great!

Comment: @w0rldart: If the array is pretty large, then you might want to stick to using `foreach` instead. `array_walk` is **slower** when done over large arrays. Also, unlike `foreach`, you can't limit the actions inside the `function(&$v) { ... }` block, as it would get executed *every* time.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran then I might not use any of these solutions at all, since they all involve some increase in the processing time, and rather use the `unset` version. Hadn't thought that `array_walk` could be slower. Thanks for the info

Comment: @w0rldart, From your question's edit , the `array_walk` still uses internal looping structures.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yea, so it seems. Well I'll stick to `unset` for now, but thanks for your solution!

Comment: @w0rldart If you do not want to write the `unset()` 4 times, save those keys in an array, and loop through those with in-relation to the first.

Comment: @w0rldart, I don't understand why you need `unset()` , Can't you just recreate them to a new array using that same `foreach` ? Added an example on the code using a `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$replace = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
foreach($replace AS $key) {
    $input[$key] = $input['referral_' . $key];
    unset($input[$input['referral_' .$key]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below one...

```
$input = [
   //'first_name'   => 'Alex',
   // 'last_name'    => 'UFO',
   // 'email'        => 'test@test.com',
    //'phone_number' => '124124',
    // .....
    'referral_first_name'   => 'Jason',
    'referral_last_name'    => 'McNugget',
    'referral_email'        => 'jingleball@nuggets.com',
    'referral_phone_number' => '1212415',
];

foreach ($input as $key=>$value){
    $refereal_pos = strpos($key, 'referral_');
    if($refereal_pos !== FALSE && $refereal_pos == 0){
        $input[str_replace('referral_', '', $key)] = $value;
        unset($input[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following;

```
function changeKeys($input) {
    $keys = array_keys($input);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if (strpos($key, "referral_") !== false) {
            $tempKey = explode("referral_", $key);
            $input[$tempKey[1]] = $input[$key];
                unset($input[$key]);
        }
    }   
    return $input;
}

changeKeys($input);
```

Here is a working demo: **[codepad](http://codepad.org/0WNzo7Aq)**

**Note:** Be sure that, your keys overwrited due to duplicate keys after "referral_" removal